# Validate a number field in symfony2

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I have the following situation:
In my FormType class:

```
... 
$builder->add('fieldToValidate', 'number', array('required' => false))
...
```

In the model class:

```
...
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
...
/**
 * @var float $fieldToValidate
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="fieldToValidate", type="float", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Type(type="float", message="Must be a number.")
 */
private $fieldToValidate;
```

In the action in controller:

```
$entity = $this->getService('my_service')->findMyEntity($entityId);
$editForm = $this->createForm(new MyEntityType(), $entity, $myOptions);
$request = $this->getRequest();
$editForm->bindRequest($request);
if ($editForm->isValid()){
```

When i submit the form with some invalid data in fieldToValidate (e.g. "foo") a got a exception:
`Expected argument of type "numeric", "boolean" given`
Debugging my code in controller i note it raise the excepction in line 
`$editForm->bindRequest($request);`
How can i make to use the `$editForm->isValid()` to control the exception. 
Is not for this i validate in model and form?

Comment: Can we wee the whole action plus the form class please? thanks

Comment: is to much code, almost of it is not important for this situation, please tell me what you are thinking could be wrong

Comment: @Oriam : have you found a solution yet? I am facing the same issue!

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * @Assert\Regex(pattern="/\d+/")
 */
```

Comment: Could you elaborate that?

Comment: its simple regexp that allows input only digits.